# Hint to compiler that it can use aligned memcpy

Tags: c, glibc, memcpy, memory-alignment, avx

I have a struct consisting of seven __m256 values, which is stored 32-byte aligned in memory.

```
typedef struct
{
        __m256 xl,xh;
        __m256 yl,yh;
        __m256 zl,zh;
        __m256i co;
} bloxset8_t;
```

I achieve the 32-byte alignment by using the `posix_memalign()` function for dynamically allocated data, or using the `(aligned(32))` attribute for statically allocated data.

The alignment is fine, but when I use two pointers to such a struct, and pass them as destination and source for memcpy() then the compiler decides to use `__memcpy_avx_unaligned()` to copy.

How can I force clang to use the aligned avx memcpy function instead, which I assume is the faster variant?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, Clang: 3.8.0-2ubuntu4.

**UPDATE**
The __memcpy_avx_unaligned() is invoked only when copying two or more structs. When copying just one, clang emits 14 vmovup instructions.

Comment: Untested, but worth a try: I think I've seen this done before by adding an `assert()` before the `memcpy` that asserts that the address is 32-byte aligned. Some compilers can take these hints and use them for optimization.

Comment: I could not reproduce this with Clang 3.9 (I get a bunch of `vmovaps`), unfortunately I can't try 3.8

Comment: @harold memcpy_avx_unaligned() is used if you copy two or more structs in one go. One struct is indeed done with move instructions, which in my case are unaligned: vmovup (and it uses 14 of them.)

Comment: I think for static / automatic storage, you're already fine for alignment. 
 `__m256` implies 32B alignment already.  But yes, you should use `aligned_alloc` or `posix_memalign` for dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__memcpy_avx_unaligned` is just an internal glibc function name. It does not mean that there is a faster `__memcpy_avx_aligned` function.  The name is just convey a hint to the glibc developers how this `memcpy` variant is implemented.

The other question is whether it would be faster for the C compiler to emit an inline expansion of `memcpy`, using four AVX2 load/store operations.  The code for that would be larger than the `memcpy` call, but it might still be faster overall.  It may be possible to help the compiler to do this using the [`__builtin_assume_aligned` builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).

Comment: Near duplicate of [perf report shows this function "\_\_memset\_avx2\_unaligned\_erms" has overhead. does this mean memory is unaligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51614543), or at least related.  I went into more detail there about how that specific glibc memset strategy works.