# Please help to understand the following memcpy code from GLIBC_2.14

Tags: assembly, x86, glibc, dispatch

```
180688 000000000009f150 <memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14>:
180689   ¦9f150:   48 8b 0d 01 bd 34 00    mov    0x34bd01(%rip),%rcx        # 3eae58 <_rtld_global_ro@GLIBC_PRIVATE>
180690   ¦9f157:   48 8d 05 d2 c3 01 00    lea    0x1c3d2(%rip),%rax        # bb530 <memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5+0x60>
180691   ¦9f15e:   8b 91 b4 00 00 00       mov    0xb4(%rcx),%edx
180692   ¦9f164:   f7 c2 00 00 08 00       test   $0x80000,%edx
180693   ¦9f16a:   75 59                   jne    9f1c5 <memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14+0x75>
180694   ¦9f16c:   89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
180695   ¦9f16e:   25 00 10 10 00          and    $0x101000,%eax
180696   ¦9f173:   3d 00 10 00 00          cmp    $0x1000,%eax
180697   ¦9f178:   74 56                   je     9f1d0 <memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14+0x80>
180698   ¦9f17a:   f6 c6 08                test   $0x8,%dh
180699   ¦9f17d:   0f 85 7d 00 00 00       jne    9f200 <memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14+0xb0>
180700   ¦9f183:   f6 41 79 02             testb  $0x2,0x79(%rcx)
180701   ¦9f187:   74 08                   je     9f191 <memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14+0x41>
180702   ¦9f189:   f7 c2 00 00 04 00       test   $0x40000,%edx
180703   ¦9f18f:   74 1f                   je     9f1b0 <memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14+0x60>
180704   ¦9f191:   f6 81 85 00 00 00 02    testb  $0x2,0x85(%rcx)
180705   ¦9f198:   48 8d 15 f1 c3 01 00    lea    0x1c3f1(%rip),%rdx        # bb590 <memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5+0xc0>
180706   ¦9f19f:   48 8d 05 2a c3 01 00    lea    0x1c32a(%rip),%rax        # bb4d0 <memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5>
180707   ¦9f1a6:   48 0f 45 c2             cmovne %rdx,%rax
180708   ¦9f1aa:   c3                      retq   
180709   ¦9f1ab:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
180710   ¦9f1b0:   83 e2 02                and    $0x2,%edx
180711   ¦9f1b3:   48 8d 05 06 d8 0c 00    lea    0xcd806(%rip),%rax        # 16c9c0 <__nss_group_lookup@GLIBC_2.2.5+0x2a10>
180712   ¦9f1ba:   48 8d 15 6f 2d 0d 00    lea    0xd2d6f(%rip),%rdx        # 171f30 <__nss_group_lookup@GLIBC_2.2.5+0x7f80>
180713   ¦9f1c1:   48 0f 45 c2             cmovne %rdx,%rax
180714   ¦9f1c5:   f3 c3                   repz retq
180715   ¦9f1c7:   66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
180716   ¦9f1ce:   00 00
180717   ¦9f1d0:   81 e2 00 00 02 00       and    $0x20000,%edx
180718   ¦9f1d6:   48 8d 05 f3 34 0f 00    lea    0xf34f3(%rip),%rax        # 1926d0 <__nss_group_lookup@GLIBC_2.2.5+0x28720>
180719   ¦9f1dd:   75 e6                   jne    9f1c5 <memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14+0x75>
180720   ¦9f1df:   f6 81 85 00 00 00 02    testb  $0x2,0x85(%rcx)
180721   ¦9f1e6:   48 8d 15 43 3f 0f 00    lea    0xf3f43(%rip),%rdx        # 193130 <__nss_group_lookup@GLIBC_2.2.5+0x29180>
180722   ¦9f1ed:   48 8d 05 cc 3e 0f 00    lea    0xf3ecc(%rip),%rax        # 1930c0 <__nss_group_lookup@GLIBC_2.2.5+0x29110>
180723   ¦9f1f4:   48 0f 45 c2             cmovne %rdx,%rax
180724   ¦9f1f8:   c3                      retq
180725   ¦9f1f9:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)
180726   ¦9f200:   f6 81 85 00 00 00 02    testb  $0x2,0x85(%rcx)
180727   ¦9f207:   48 8d 15 32 fb 0e 00    lea    0xefb32(%rip),%rdx        # 18ed40 <__nss_group_lookup@GLIBC_2.2.5+0x24d90>
180728   ¦9f20e:   48 8d 05 cb fa 0e 00    lea    0xefacb(%rip),%rax        # 18ece0 <__nss_group_lookup@GLIBC_2.2.5+0x24d30>
180729   ¦9f215:   48 0f 45 c2             cmovne %rdx,%rax
180730   ¦9f219:   c3                      retq
180731   ¦9f21a:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

The above code is dumped by objdump application. I have the following questions.

1. I couldn't find out the actual copy code. For instance, in memcpy@@GLIBC_3.XX, we could see this:

   ```
     movups xmm0, ptr qword[rsi]
     movups ptr qword[rdi], xmm0
   ```

   but in this function, we could not see such read-then-write code. How does it perform copy operation?

Comment: GCC is the place where it's implemented (through the `__builtin_memcpy` function.) Not sure where exactly the source for it is though in the GCC code base. When GCC sees a call to `memcpy()`, it will usually replace it with an inlined `__builtin_memcpy()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like glibc's dynamic linking resolver function that returns a function pointer (in `%rax`) based on CPUID, e.g. selecting the AVX version on CPUs that support it.

This resolver override runs once, during dynamic linking (e.g. on the first call if you use *lazy* dynamic linking).

And yes, this is the code you'll find at the symbol name `memcpy`.

Related: [perf report shows this function "__memset_avx2_unaligned_erms" has overhead. does this mean memory is unaligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51614543) talks about that memset implementation, which the generic dispatcher selected on that asker's CPU.

Note that glibc is open source, you can look at the hand-written *commented* asm source like for its memcpy / memmove implementations, e.g.  https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-avx-unaligned-erms.S.html